# CSS glassy slightly folded borders 3D effect

Tags: css

I am trying to get the similar kind of look ( see the below image) using CSS . This has all the borders are slightly folded and has lite 3D look . I tried using box-shadow and pasted the code below . This gives me some what similar kind of shape but can not get fine one and also using two DIVs to get that effect . Can we get using a single DIV ..? Thank You

[image]

```css
.div-1 {
  width:150px;
  height:300px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  border-radius: 10px;
 }

.div-2 {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  box-shadow: width:100%;height:100%;box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa inset;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="div-1">
    <div class="div-2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can go like this :

```css
.div-1 {
  width:150px;
  height:300px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
  border-radius: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="div-1">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You @sandwell , But the inset shadow is missing to the bottom border . Could you please check it ?

Comment: @Bujji I increased a little bit the opacity and the offset-y of the box-shadow property. You can play with it to have the desired effect :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.div-1 {
 width:150px;
 height:300px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23), 0 0 5px #aaa inset;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position:relative;
  display:block;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <div class="div-1">
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank You @developer kt for this snippet . This works great . But thinking is there any way we can do using single box-shadow to get this effect .